# How to override Error stack getter

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

My goal is to write a new class that will extend javascripts native Error class in order to support better stack messages.

so what i want to do is to still be able to call error.stack but to get a better stack message, which will also include the original stack trace plus some more data of my own.

i am not sure how to achieve this goal:

```
'use strict'
    class MyError extends Error {
        constructor(error) {
            super(error);
        }

        get stack() {
            return "extended" + this.stack;
        }
    }

    var error = new MyError("my error");
    console.log(error.stack);
```

but what i get is just the original stack message without the new data.

Comment: How are you executing this? Which environment does already support subclassing builtins?

Comment: node.js supports EC6

Comment: You mean ES6? And node does not yet fully support it, so you never know.

Comment: sorry,ES6. node 4+ does support ES6.

Comment: [Not all of it](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/)! It appears subclassing builtins works only in strict mode, so please be precise about what you are doing.

Comment: you are right. but subclassing does work as you said with strict mode and that's what i am talking about. sorry for leaving out the strict. i will fix

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should do much more work for extending Error class:

```
class MyError extends Error {
    constructor(message) {
        super(message);
        this.name = this.constructor.name;
        this.message = message; 

        // standard way: Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor.name);
        // if you do this, you couldn't set different getter for the 'stack' property
        this.stack = new Error().stack; // do this, if you need a custom getter
    }

    get stack() {
        return "extended " + this._stack;
    }

    set stack(stack) {
      this._stack = stack; 
    }
}

try {
    throw new MyError('My error');
} catch(e) {
    console.log(e.stack);
}
```

In case the platform you're using doesn't support getters/setters, you could use Object.defineProperty:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    class MyError extends Error {
        constructor(message) {
            super(message);
            this.name = this.constructor.name;
            this.message = message; 

            Object.defineProperty(this, 'stack', {
                get: function() { return 'extended ' + this._stack; },
                set: function(value) { this._stack = value; }
            });

            this.stack = new Error().stack;
        }
    }

    try {
        throw new MyError('test');
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.stack);
    }
}());
```

Comment: thanks. can you explain why the first way would not allow setting a different getter for 'stack'?

Comment: i tried this is node 4.4 but it does not work. all i get is the regular error without 'extended'

Comment: It seems that getter and setter are not supported in node 4.4. Anyway, I've added the working example, wich use Object.defineProperty. It should work. :)

Comment: It's worth noting that *getting* value of `new Error().stack` property can result in noticeable performance hit (I had stable 40+ms on stack get from first error since program startup, Node14) in *some scenarios*. This is because internally stack isn't really attached to Error until it is accessed, for performance reasons. If it matters, it's better to do it this way: `class MyErr extends Error { _stackObj = {}; constructor(message) { /*...*/ Error.captureStackTrace(this._stackObj, this.constructor /* not .name */); } get stack() { return this._stackObj.stack; } }`

Comment: @AndriiM4n0w4R Nice, you should add that as another answer on this question!